# iOS UILabel is higher than text

Tags: ios, text, uilabel, height

[image]

[image]

Just like the picture above.

I found the problem.
When I set the linespace to attributeText,if there is only one line,the height of 'UILabel' is higher than Text.If there are more than one line, they are the same.

How to resolve it?

`sizeToFits` is useless and `boundingRectWithSize` is useless.

Don't care about the missing part of text~

Comment: did u try to change the `Auto Shrink` in storyboard to `Minimum font scale` and see?

Comment: I didn't use storyboard.I just use code.   the picture is  from ‘Debug View Hierarchy’  @Tj3n

Answer (score 0):

if you use the autoLayout,you needn't to set the height-value of the label .and the another way is calculating the text of UILabel ,and set the result value

```
-(CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size{
NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
return rect.size;
```

}

Comment: What I use was 'autoLayout' and didn't set the height of UIlabel,and then the height of UIlabel is higher that text...     Is it result from Chinese Word?